Meaning of the end of chapter 2, Naive set theory – Halmos
Can someone give an alternative explanation of the latter part of chapter 2 of Halmos, “The axiom of specification”?
I just don’t get what the notation ${\epsilon}´$ means.
(I interpret that Halmos use of ${\epsilon}$ in the text is equivalent to the symbol ${\in}$.)
I'm ok with $B=\{ x \: \epsilon \: A : S(x) \}$
and that $x \: {\epsilon}´$ A is equivalent to $x \notin$ A .
What I need help with is:

... in this notation, the role of S(x) is now played by
$$x \:{\epsilon}´ \:x$$
... whatever set A may be, if $ B = \{x \:{\epsilon} \: A: x \:{\epsilon}´ \:x \} $ ...


The Axiom of Specification says that if $A$ is a set, and $S(x)$ is a sentence in which $x$ is free, then
$$\{x\in A\mid S(x)\}$$
is a set.
The sentence
$$x\notin x$$
is a sentence in which $x$ is free. So if $A$ is a set, then
$$B=\{ x\in A\mid x\notin x\}$$
is a set by the Axiom of Specification. Change $A$, and the set $B$ may change. This is a subset of $A$, regardless of what $A$ may be.
Then Halmos shows that whatever $B$ might be, it is not an element of $A$. This proves that in this set theory, there is no "universal set":  there is no set that contains all sets as elements. Why? Because if $A$ is any set, then we can find a set that is not an element of $A$, namely, the set
$$ \{x\in A\mid x\notin x\}.$$
For most sets $A$, in most set theories, the set $B$ will be equal to $A$. But in principle, at this stage of development, there could be sets that are elements of themselves (and in some set theories there are such elements). For example, if there were a set $a$ such that $a\in a$, and $A=\{a\}$, then the set $\{x\in A\mid x\notin x\}$ would equal $\varnothing$... which is in fact not an element of $A$.

The condition $x \ \epsilon' \ y$ means only that $y$ may or may not be a set, and if it is, it means that $x$ is not an element of $y$.
In the examples that you mentioned, $B = \{ x \ \epsilon A : x \ \epsilon' \ x \}$, the elements of $B$ are those that belong to $A$, are sets, and do not belong to themselves. In the end, Halmos proves that such a set (that exists) don't belongs to A.

No, Halmos is using $\in'$ as a typographical synonym of $\notin$. The book was written before the time of $\LaTeX$, and this was possibly just typographical convenience. It does not reflect anything about whether $x$ may or may not be a set.  Halmos says "It will be convenient, here and throughout, to write $x\in' A$ (alternatively, "$x\notin A$") instead of "not ($x\in A$)"[.]" It is just an abbreviation for "$x$ is not an element of $A$".

Yes, this is what I'm saying. The notation $x \in x$ only makes sense if $x$ is a set.

You are implying that using $x\notin y$ somehow implies that there is no assumption that $x$ is a set. This is not any more accurate than to say that within the context of set theory, writing $x\in y$ should be read to mean "$x$ may or may not be a set, and $y$  may or may not be a set, but if both are sets, then $x$ is an element of $y$." That is simply not what the notation means in this context. Claiming so is to claim that every notation needs to be read with a prefix saying "maybe this is all nonsense, but if  it is not nonsense, then this is what it means." That's absurd.

But you changed the context, and I'm not saying that. In your example, $x \notin y$, I'm not saying that $x$ may or may not be a set. I'm saying that the condition only makes sense if $y$ (and not $x$) is a set. In the end, we are saying the same, I guess.

You are explicitly saying that the notation should be read as saying that "$x$ may or may not be a set". That is literally the first thing you say after "means". And since this is a question about the meaning of the notation in set theory, disclaiming its meaning when you are not talking about sets is silly.

Yes, you are right; perhaps I was not clear enough in my explanation. I believed that for Clive Long, the meaning of $x \notin A$ when $A$ is a set was clear enough, and that he was having trouble with the specific notation $x \notin x$. I am editing my answer for more clarity; thank you.

@CarlosLicea Yes, I think my problem is about understanding the meaning of x $\notin$ x, as you have written. I will study your and Arturo's responses.
